# NginxInc/kubernetes-ingress - Opening portainer websocket connections - Passing headers

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, portainer

Reporting a solution here for future reference as I couldn't find any single resource when I was implementing this:

Using the [nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress) controller **not** the [kubernetes/ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx).

Problem started in [portainer v2.1.1](https://github.com/portainer/portainer), but if you ever need to create an ingress rule and pass headers through, or apply any specific rules.

Issue codes:

```
Unable to upgrade the connection (err=websocket: the client is not using the websocket protocol: 'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header) (code=500)

WebSocket connection to 'ws://portainer.example.com/.....// failed
```

Comment: Hi @Diarmuid and welcome on Stack :) for better visibility and with the purpose of helping other community members, it would be beneficial to post a question and a separate answer. You will then be able to accept it for increased visibility. I would also recommend to familiarize with the guidelines you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [Nginx websocket proxying guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html)
A minimal solution using [Nginx snippets](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-snippets/):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: portainer-ingress
  namespace: portainer
  annotations:
    nginx.org/location-snippets: |
      proxy_set_header   Upgrade            $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header   Connection         "upgrade";
    
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    -  host: portainer.example.com
       http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: portainer
                port:
                  number: 9000
            pathType: Prefix
```

Running [Nginx ingress controller version v1.10.1](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.10.1) installed using [manifests](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/)

```
helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-3.23.0
app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.44.0
```

I hope this helps someone as a reference